# reproduce this in vb.net in an asp:repeater i need to repeat the following

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, asprepeater

I need to repeat the following in vb.net/asp.net.

```
<ul id="prod_nav" class="clearfix">
      <li class="top"><a href="05-Pink-02-Category-List.html" class="top_link"><span class="down">Body and Trim</span></a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="clearfix">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html">Panels</a></li>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html">Tow Bars</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>   <li class="top"><a href="05-Pink-02-Category-List.html" class="top_link"><span class="down">Brake Friction</span></a>
        <ul class="sub">
          <li class="clearfix">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html">Drums</a></li>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html">pads</a></li>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html">discs</a></li>

            </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

so ar i have

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterMyList"  Runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>

            </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <li class="top"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="top_link"><span class="down"></span><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"groupname")%></a>

          <ul class="sub">
          <li class="clearfix">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subgroupname")%></a></li>




                </ItemTemplate>
                <SeparatorTemplate>

            </ul>
                </SeparatorTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>

                </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
```

**Problem** : The datatable I have referenced the repeater in, has the columns for example but im only getting one master `<li>`.

Created please can someone help me out here.

```
GROUPID   GROUPNAME           SUBGROUPID SUGROUPNAME
BO  Body & Trim PANE-BO Panels
BO  Body & Trim TOWS-BO Tow Bars

BR  Brake Friction  DRUM-BR Drums
BR  Brake Friction  PADS-BR Pads
BR  Brake Friction  KITS-BR Accessories-Fit Kits
BR  Brake Friction  DISC-BR Discs
BR  Brake Friction  SHOE-BR Shoes
CA  Cables  CABL-CA Cables
CA  Cables  CAFP-CA Cable Fitment Parts
CL  Clutch Friction SSCL-CL Switches, Sensors - Clutch
CL  Clutch Friction CLPT-CL Clutch Parts, Flywheels
CL  Clutch Friction CLFP-CL Fitting Parts
CO  Cooling & Heating   RCTS-CO Radiator Caps, Thermostats
CO  Cooling & Heating   SSCH-CO Switches, Sensors - Cooling & Heating   
CO  Cooling & Heating   WHOP-CO Water Hoses, Pumps
```

Comment: Looks like you need something more complicated than plain `Repeater`.. what about the `Menu` control? Or client side jQuery menu?

Comment: within `<li class="clearfix">` in your example, there are two `<ul>` - why? What do they correspond to in your data example?

Comment: can you be more specific the line numbers

Comment: It's clear now after your last edit - I added a markup example for the nested repeaters to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the full solution which would involve more than just the markup for the repeater, here is the most important subject you should look into to pull this off:

**Nested repeaters**

Tons of examples on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nested%20repeaters) and elsewhere.

Basically, you'll want a repeater for your *groups*, and and inner repeater for your *subgroups*.

Hard to be more specific because the data table you mention in your question does not correspond to the markup sample provided (for example, the group *Bathroom* cannot be found in your data example).

EDIT:

Here's the basic markup for a nested repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rGroups"  Runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul id="prod_nav" class="clearfix">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="top"><a href="05-Pink-02-Category-List.html" class="top_link">
            <span class="down"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"groupname")%></span></a>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rSubgroups"  Runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <ul class="sub">
                  <li class="clearfix">
                    <ul>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li><a href="05-Pink-03-Products-List.html"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"subgroupname")%></a></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The *rSubgroups* repeater needs to be bound for each item in the *rGroups* repeater. In order to do that, you'll need to implement the `OnItemDataBound` event of *rGroups*

Comment: the markup was an example the data is the data i need to reproduce within the repeater

Comment: do u have an example how to do that i have a dataset which i reference in repearter one ds.tables(1)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571363/nested-repeaters-in-asp-net/3571394#3571394 contains an example on how to set up OnItemDataBound and how to use FindControl to obtain a reference to the inner repeater.

Comment: when i rung the example though it reproduces 3 main elements of body and trim if i just run it as standard

Comment: You cannot bind the data list directly to rGroups. First you'll need to obtain a list of unique groups and bind that to rGroups. Then, for every group bound, you'll bind the list of subgroups for that particular group to the rSubgroups repeater.

Comment: if my information is in the dataset ds.tables(1) how can i do a select on that as im going out to a webservice to fetch that data first

Comment: Linq to the rescue - see the accepted answer of this question (covers exactly this case) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686589/c-dataset-retrieving-unique-value-based-on-column

Comment: CAN YOU GIVE ME AN EXAMPLE OF HOW TO bound rsubgroups please im running into difculity

Comment: in ur example i catn seem to reference the subgroups repeater in coe can you give examples